# Locale-aware uppercase in Bash?

Tags: bash, locale

How to make locale aware uppercase operation?

Standard tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' trick doesn't work:

```
=$ echo żółw | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"
żółW
```

(it should be ŻÓŁW)

I'd rather avoid having to run Perl or anything such heavy-weight.

Comment: This is not about "bash", if you're running tr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that if you want to avoid a heavyweight you'd need to provide the characters yourself, and, given that's a nonstarter for a truly generic solution, you are stuck with using a heavyweight.

One heavyweight solution

```
vinko@parrot:~$ more t.py
# coding: UTF-8
print unicode.upper("żółw".decode('utf-8'))
vinko@parrot:~$ python t.py
ŻÓŁW
```

Non-heavyweight solution that would require you to specify each character

```
vinko@parrot:~$ echo żół | tr "[żół]" "[ŻÓŁ]"
ŻÓŁ
```

EDIT: Based on the other answer and comments, BASH 4.0 IS locale sensitive and aware of wide chars. You have to set a proper locale of course (LC_CTYPE or LC_ALL) so BASH can tell what it is supposed to do. Also it seems that there are locale sensitive versions of tr as of late (for example, Mac OSX 10.6)

Comment: Well - python is in the range of things I'd like to avoid. Too heavy. As for specifying each character - while it is simple for "żółw", it becomes practically impossible to make it generally working.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in the first paragraph. As far as I know and as far as I could find, there is no unicode aware version of tr, nor BASH is aware of wide characters.

Comment: Actually, on OS X and probably FreeBSD, tr *is* locale-aware and the OP's example works.

Comment: @Ned which versions? Are those Apple's and FreeBSD's mods or upstream?

Comment: The manpage for *tr* in Mac OS X 10.6 (http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/tr.1.html) certainly says it is locale sensitive, but *tr* is not locale sensitive in back in 10.4.

Answer (score 2):

If you bash is new enough, it may be able to do it (see [bash-4.0 NEWS item 1.hh.](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS)).

```
bash -c 'foo="żółw"; echo ${foo^^}'
```

zsh, too (since 4.3.3?):

```
zsh -c 'foo="żółw"; echo ${(U)foo}'
```

Comment: Mine is 4.0.35, also. What are your locale settings? You probably need to at least set LC_CTYPE to a UTF-8 variation (see `locale -a | fgrep UTF-8`). If `locale` reports that everything is just `C`, then it will not work. My LC_CTYPE is `en_US.UTF-8`.